# How do I convert my sed insert text script in PHP?

Tags: php, ubuntu, nginx, replace, sed

I have a working sed script that inserts text to a document at the line number.

```
sed -i '35i \ NewPage,' file
```

wondering if theres a way i can achive the same result using php.
35 i is the row number to be inserted 
\ make the insert in a new line
NewPage is the text being inserted
file is the file location

Any suggestions?
Best regards
AT.

Answer (score 1):

You can but can't be oneliner like `sed`

**Sample Input**

```
akshay@db-3325:/tmp$ seq 1 5 > test.txt
akshay@db-3325:/tmp$ cat test.txt 
1
2
3
4
5
```

**Output with sed at line number 4**

```
akshay@db-3325:/tmp$ sed '4i \ NewPage,' test.txt 
1
2
3
 NewPage,
4
5
```

**PHP Script**

```
akshay@db-3325:/tmp$ cat test.php 
<?php
$new_contents = " NewPage,";
$file     = "test.txt";
$line     = 4;

$contents = file($file); 
array_splice($contents, $line-1, 0, $new_contents.PHP_EOL);
file_put_contents($file, implode("",$contents));
?>
```

**Execution and Output**

```
akshay@db-3325:/tmp$ php test.php 
akshay@db-3325:/tmp$ cat test.txt 
1
2
3
 NewPage,
4
5
```

OR else you have to use `exec`, but careful if you are enabling `exec` in your server, usually people disable these functions in their `php.ini` configuration

```
exec("sed -i '35i \ NewPage,' path/to/file 2>&1", $outputAndErrors, $return_value);
if (!$return_value) {
    // Alright command executed successfully 
}
```

> Note : In general functions such as “exec” and “system” are always
>   used to execute the external programs. Even a shell command can also
>   be executed. If these two functions are enabled then a user can enter
>   any command as input and execute into your server.